# How to use tshark or tcpdump to calculate bytes transmitted

Tags: log-files, tcpdump, pcap, tshark

I am using this command with tshark:

```
tshark -r pcapfile "tcp and ip.src==192.168.1.1" -T text -V -x | grep 'Total Length'
```

This essentially parses the pcap for only connections from the source ip and looks for the total length in bytes from each packet. I get output like this:

```
Total Length: 125 
Total Length: 210 
Total Length: 40 
Total Length: 125
> etc, etc....
```

What I need to do is take the numbers from Total Length and add them up so I can get an idea of how much data was passed over the wire in the time frame of the pcap from a single IP.

Is there a command I can add on the end of the one I am using to do this? Or is there a way I can direct to stdout and then pipe that to a program that can parse and calculate what I am after? Anyone know of a similar command with tcpdump that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` can sum up a column of numbers. Something like this should do the trick.

Assuming that the output of your tshark is in `foo.txt`:

```
$ cat foo.txt | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }'
```

You could also pipe the output of "grep" directly to `awk`, and it would work in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 5):

You can rely purely on `tshark` to do this, by using the statistics option with the IO stat calculator :

```
tshark -r pcapfile -z io,stat,0,"SUM(frame.len)frame.len && ip.src == 192.168.1.1 && ip.proto == 6"
```

This will show a board where the `SUM` column is the data you are looking for.